# Rails for xml request why we need to specify format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For html and ajax request we don't need to specify the format but for xml request we need to specify the format like `:format => 'xml'`

```
 <%= button_to t('.add_html'), line_items_path(:product_id => product, :format => 'xml'),  :product => product.id %>
```

Why we have to specify the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit a page by visiting a link, the browser actually specifies in the headers that it accepts HTML as the response type:

[image: typical browser visit]

When an AJAX request is submitted, the browser actually appends a header to the request called `X-Requested-With` flagging the request as an `XMLHttpRequest`:

[image: AJAX]

Since these headers exist, the server knows what to respond with. To visit the `xml` format of the page, you have to tell the server to that you want the XML format. If you were programmatically build your request, you could set the `Accept` header to `text/xml` and the server would respond with the XML response